# Working with variables in Unix

Tags: shell, variables, unix

I have a variable `$x` that has a value of a position of an argument to the script (say 8). I need to capture the value in the 8th argument (say 1) into another variable `y` and be able to use that as variable `$y` ($1) to refer to a column in a file.

Comment: To clarify your question, please show the function with the 8 or 9 arguments. Also please state your question. (I do not see a question mark)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. please include sample input and expected output from that data, as well as your best attempt to solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Which shell are you using?  The answers for bash, csh, dash, ksh, zsh will be different.  Also, when you say 'refer to a column in a file', what does that mean?  You'll be passing it to `cut` or `awk` or using directly in the shell, somehow, maybe as an array subscript?  You should show what you've tried — your best effort — and explain what's wrong with it; that's part of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the indirect reference `${!var}` to do this:

```
set one two three four five six seven eight
x=8
y=${!x}
echo $y
```

You get this output:

```
eight
```

Comment: If the OP is using Bash (or maybe a related shell).  That isn't universally supported.